# is there any option ntpq for the ntp server connectivity test like ntpdate -d command?

Tags: esxi, ntp, ntpd, ntpdate

Is there any option ntpq for the ntp server connectivity test like the ntpdate -d command?

> ntpdate -d ntpserverip

This command shows the suitable ntp server for synchronization. What the equivalent for the ntpq command?

> ntpdate -d ntpserverip
>   adjust time server ntpserverip offset 0.101886 sec --> for success response
>
> ntpdate -d ntpserverip
>    no server suitable for synchronization found --> for fail response

This ntpserverip is not in the ntp.conf. I want to test different a NTP server which is not in the ntp.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re missing the deprecated `ntpdate`, `sntp` is a better substitute than `ntpq`.

By default, `sntp`*`ntpserverip`* will query the time without setting the clock (like options `-q` and `-d` of `ntpdate` did), using a random port (like options `-u` and `-d` of `ntpdate` did).

Optionally, include:

- `-4` or `-6` to force IPv4 or IPv6 DNS resolution.
- `-d` for debugging mode (may be repeated to increase level).
- `-r` if you need to use NTP port 123 (if `ntpd` isn’t already using it).
- `-a`*`keyid`* if you need MAC authentication.

See also:

- Full usage: [sntp - Simple Network Time Protocol (SNTP) Client](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/sntp.html)
- [Deprecating ntpdate](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate): includes usage equivalences between `ntpdate`, `sntp` and `ntpd`.
- [Basic NTP client test: ntpdate & sntp](https://weberblog.net/basic-ntp-client-test-ntpdate-sntp/): a blog page by Johannes Weber showing sample outputs of both `ntpdate` and `sntp` while testing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `ntpdate -q ntpserverip`?

Otherwise `ntpq host ntpserverip` might be what you want.  It sets the host to query. http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpq.htm

EDIT for ESXi

This give a good walkthrough of NTP in the web interface: https://blog.ukotic.net/2014/09/11/configuring-and-testing-ntp-on-esxi/

When you set it, you can add multiple NTP servers to the list and use the ntpq to query it then.  There's a VMware KB article mentioned in that link that pertains to several versions of ESXi.

Comment: hi Bryan, there is no ntpdate package in the esxi host therefore I don't use ntpdate. I think this ntpq host ntpserverip not the same ntpdate -d command . I can't running the command. This command prints the name or service not known output.

Comment: Could you add in the ESXi version to the question? I removed the Linux tag to the question and added ESXi.  ESXi is a "Unix like OS" and more of a stripped down version.  If you put a Linux VM on the same vNIC as as the ESXi host's management you can use ntpdate from there. Alternatively you just set the desired NTP in the DCUI or web interface and look and post the results to `tail /var/log/messages | grep ntpd` as well

Comment: hi, brain there is no different ntpq package between esxi and linux. All of them use the same options. I think misunderstood my question. ntpdate -d anyntpserverip command shows us connection success and offset between anyntpserverip and ntp client which I run ntpdate command. I want to same result with ntpq command. ntpq -p localhost or ntpserverip show us peers at the server which run ntpq command on the server